# How to fill ImageView background by multiplying small image not scaling?

Tags: android, imageview

How can I fill entire ImageView background with small image (eg. 2x2px)?
I have found many answers how to stretch image to fill ImageView but I can't find one how to multiple image to fill whole ImageView.

If in ImageView it's imposible it could be any other View.

Comment: is it just one 2x2 px image ?

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12369221/3049917)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a bitmap xml for your image:

drawable/tiled_background.xml

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Note the `android:tileMode="repeat"` line - it will make the image tile over the background. And now simple assign the xml as the background:

Comment: If you find the answer satisfying, please mark it as correct. Thanks! :-)