# Android Zig-Zag layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, zigzag

I'm in need of creating a receipt layout in Android. The idea is very simple, a rectangle layout with a zigzag top.

[image]

Even, i have tried dashed line but nothing working.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line">

<stroke
   android:color="#FF00"
   android:dashWidth="5dp"
   android:dashGap="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761179/android-bottom-zig-zag-shape

Comment: @SlowAndSteady i have seen this post earlier but it didnt help.

Comment: Hey! did you solve your problem...If yes can you please tell me how

Answer (score 7):

Try with this: https://github.com/beigirad/ZigzagView

Support `top` and `bottom` Zigzag.

```
<ir.beigirad.zigzagview.ZigzagView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    app:zigzagBackgroundColor="#8bc34a"
    app:zigzagElevation="8dp"
    app:zigzagHeight="10dp"
    app:zigzagShadowAlpha="0.9"
    app:zigzagSides="top|bottom"
    app:zigzagPaddingContent="16dp">

    // add child view(s)

</ir.beigirad.zigzagview.ZigzagView>
```

[image: ZizagView]

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this library [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview). And use transparent shape like this

End use library.

[image]

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:siShape="@drawable/zigzag"
android:src="@drawable/neo"
app:siSquare="true"/>
```

[image]

You can change `app:siShape="@drawable/zigzag"` to desired shape. You can create other png shape.

Comment: i dont want zig zag at all the 4 corners. Only top. Hence, this wont work for me.Thanks

Comment: i also want top two corners(top left and top right) to be rounded/curved...what will be my approch?

Answer (score 1):

Create small triangle and use repeat background

repeat_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/imagename"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

and use it in any view

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat_background" />
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706913/how-to-make-android-apps-background-image-repeat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262735/repeat-image-in-with-imageview-in-relativelayout) for more